# Best way to make StringTemplate limit the length of a string?

Tags: java, jsp, stringtemplate

This is easiest to explain using a code example. In some scenarios, we have list items that have a lot of text, but showing more than the first few words is not useful, this is how we deal with it in JSP:

```
<% for(Item item : items) { %>
<li><%=StringHelper.shorten(item.getValue(),30))%></a></li>
<% } %>
```

The filter has some logic that makes it avoid cutting words, and including a "..." to indicate truncation, and so on. ie:

```
<li>Some text</li>
<li>Some other text that is longer...</li>
```

Is there a neat way to do this with a formatter. I know I could probably do something like this, but it seems a bit hacky, as we use different numbers in different locations:

```
$items:{i|<li>$i.value;format="max30"$</li>}$
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to customize a tag, e.g.

```
public class ShortenTag extends TagSupport{

  private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 30; 

  public int doStartTag(){

    // shorten string here
  }


}
```

Comment: A google search for "stringtemplate TagSupport" basically only returns this post. I'll see if there is any info on this thing you mention.